# P4 Root and Altroot across Windows and Linux

Tags: git, perforce, p4v

I have a P4 client that I share across both Linux and Windows environment, using the 'Root' (Linux) and 'Altroot' parameters within the client spec ('Host' is removed).  Does anyone know if it is possible to configure P4 to mirror the directories across the two platforms?  What I mean is, if I check out a file and make edits within my Linux workspace, can I somehow configure P4 to update the workspace on my Windows box to have the same file opened and edited before the file is checked into the repository?  I don't think this is possible, but I'm asking just in case someone knows of a way.

edit: Is it possible to do this with Git?  All source is stored in a P4 repo in work, but I could setup a local Git repo if this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single perforce clientspec is supposed to only refer to a single copy of the files.

You should share the files from your Linux machine to your Windows machine, or visa-versa, then when they are open for edit, they could be edited from either side.

You could create two separate client-specs, and use shelving to move files between them, or create your own branch, that the two clients share, and then checkin to that branch, and merge to your current codeline once you've completed the work.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more on how to share a branch over 2 client-specs? And how to copy/sync over the change from one client to another? Thanks.

Comment: @Stan I'm not sure what more I can add: Setup a branch, commit changes on either machine, sync on the other machine to get the changes.

Comment: @Stan to setup the branch, use the old-school appropriate with `p4 integrate`, (and probably a branch-spec for easy of use), or use perforce streams to get an easier display of the branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a shared drive this will work. I work on windows, but also have to develop in a Linux VM. Using VMware I can mount drive to a share in one of my windows folders, and set my p4root to the windows folder, and my altroot to the same folder in linux, but using the share/mounted drive. When I check out, it is in the same folder, and same physical drive.

You could do the same using mounted/mapped drives, just make your less used OS be the one that does the development over the networked drive. I have done this, but it was only briefly.